# How to pass in a function for define-key's DEF

Tags: key-bindings, spacemacs

I'm using spacemacs and setting a binding with `spacemacs/set-leader-keys`. The documentation for this states that it uses `define-key`:

> spacemacs/set-leader-keys is a Lisp function in ‘core-keybindings.el’.
>
> (spacemacs/set-leader-keys KEY DEF &rest BINDINGS)
>
> Add KEY and DEF as key bindings under
> ‘dotspacemacs-leader-key’ and ‘dotspacemacs-emacs-leader-key’.
> KEY should be a string suitable for passing to ‘kbd’, and it
> should not include the leaders. DEF is most likely a quoted
> command. See ‘define-key’ for more information about the possible
> choices for DEF. This function simply uses ‘define-key’ to add
> the bindings.
>
> For convenience, this function will accept additional KEY DEF
> pairs. For example,
>
> (spacemacs/set-leader-keys
> "a" ’command1
> "C-c" ’command2
> "bb" ’command3)

`spacemacs/set-leader-keys` sets the name of the binding in the minibuffer to whatever function it's bound to. Right now I have:

```lisp
(spacemacs/set-leader-keys "ic" (kbd "o { RET } <escape> O"))
```

so the binding name is the literal keystrokes. I'd like to be able to put the kbd statement in a function so the function name can be used:

```lisp
(defun insert-code-block ()
  (kbd "o { RET } <escape> O"))
(spacemacs/set-leader-keys "ic" #'insert-code-block)
```

When doing so I get this error:

```
command-execute: Wrong type argument: commandp, insert-code-block
```

How do I make this work?

---

If you need to know the point of this binding, the binding adds a "code block". So if I type:

```c
void this()
```

and issue the mnemonic `SPC i c`, I get a code block with the cursor (`|`) properly positioned:

```c
void this()
{
    |
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead:

```lisp
(spacemacs/set-leader-keys "ic" (insert-code-block))
```

It apparently expects, as argument, the *result* of invoking your function, not your function itself.

Comment: While this does work, it doesn't solve the naming issue. It still shows the keystrokes which makes sense because that's the result. I will mark as solved if that is out of scope.

Comment: [Using `fset` works for the naming](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/70758/28734) as I figured out here, but since you actually solved the error I was facing, and since I have linked the alternative, I will mark this as the solution.