# How to write a Lisp representation of a keyboard macro and bind it to a command name?

Tags: commands, keyboard-macros

I'm using spacemacs with vim-bindings, but I only mention it so you
don't scratch your head too long at the keystrokes of the macro. A
regular emacs solution will work just the same.

I've read through the [naming and saving section of the
manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Save-Keyboard-Macro.html).
This is nice but it's a lot of steps and the output is verbose and
unpleasing to the eye:

```lisp
(fset 'insert-code-block
   (kmacro-lambda-form [?o ?\{ return ?\} escape ?O escape] 0 "%d"))
```

I've also read [this post with similar naming](https://stackoverflow.com/q/753459/4682839).

I would like to use something like `kbd` syntax:

```lisp
(kbd "o { RET } <escape> O")
```

For reference, this was the keychord binding I used with regular emacs:

```lisp
(key-chord-define-global "xb" (kbd "RET { RET RET } C-p TAB"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out you can just use the `kbd` function:

```lisp
(fset 'insert-code-block
   (kbd "o { RET } <escape> O"))
```

Comment: FYI - you can accept your own answer (you may need to wait some period first; dunno).

Comment: Yes, was in the waiting period. Thank you for the reminder though!